# beautifulSoup 4 works on python2.6?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-2.6

I'm trying to do a web scraping project using bs4, but on the remote server they have python 2.6.6 installed.

Can I work with bs4 on python2.6.6?

I already tried but got these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/infoforense/public_html/citius-scraping.py", line 16, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 12, in <module>
    import soupsieve
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/soupsieve/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .__meta__ import __version__, __version_info__  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/soupsieve/__meta__.py", line 190, in <module>
    __version__ = __version_info__._get_canonical()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/soupsieve/__meta__.py", line 146, in _get_canonical
    ver = "{}.{}.{}".format(self.major, self.minor, self.micro)
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the failing dependency soupsieve, and can verify that soupsieve does not support Python 2.6.

It is possible that that an earlier version of Beautiful Soup (before 4.7) does fully support Python 2.6, but I'm not sure.

Python 2.6 is such an old version that even the Python team has stopped supporting it.

You could try installing older versions of Beautiful Soup and see if one of them allow you to move forward, but I can confirm that the latest versions, at least 4.7 and above, will not work on Python 2.6.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. I know that is a old version!:-) But the server provider where my company has all the projects, they use python 2.6.6! I have to use it and test with BeautifulSoup3! that's life! Thank you anyway.